# php write file path from two different location

Tags: php, file, directory, path

I have a php class used to manage write/read/delete files. The constructor receives the path (string) of the file. Basically something like:

```
class customFile{
    public function __construct($path){
        $this->path=$path;
    }

    public function write($content){
        //use fopen and fwrite to write content
    }
    public function read(){
        //use fopen and fgets to read content
    }
    public function delete(){
        //use unlink to delete the file
    }
}
```

Also I have this directory tree

```
├─ root/
│  ├─ helpers/
│  │  ├─ customFile.php
│  ├─ dir1/
│  │  ├─ function1.php
│  ├─ tempDir/
│  ├─ function2.php
│  ├─ useCustomFileFunction.php
```

Is very important to say that useCustomFileFunction.php is in charge of writing the files in the tempDir, so that function create a customFile object with a path like this "./tempDir/"+someName (for example "./tempDir/writtenFile.txt).

both function1.php and function2.php call useCustomFileFunction with some file name (to write some files) but when the function is called from function1.php the result is (incorrect):

```
├─ root/
│  ├─ helpers/
│  │  ├─ customFile.php
│  ├─ dir1/
│  │  ├─ function1.php
│  │  ├─ tempDir/
│  │  │  ├─ writtenFile.txt
│  ├─ tempDir/
│  ├─ function2.php
│  ├─ useCustomFileFunction.php
```

and when is called from function2.php, the result is (correct):

```
├─ root/
│  ├─ helpers/
│  │  ├─ customFile.php
│  ├─ dir1/
│  │  ├─ function1.php
│  ├─ tempDir/
│  │  ├─ writtenFile.txt
│  ├─ function2.php
│  ├─ useCustomFileFunction.php
```

So the question is: Is there a way to tell fwrite, that the path begin from the class/that call fwrite? (customFile1.php or useCustomFileFunction.php instead of function1.php and function2.php)

Comment: function1 should use `customFile` class with `../tempDir` path.It's a better way to use the `__FILE__` or `__DIR__` for addressing. If I was you I would create a `cofig.php` and make define a constant for the `tempDir` folder.

Comment: i used a config.php file and it works! thank u so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function1.php should use `customFile` class with `../tempDir` path.It's a better way to use the `__FILE__` or `__DIR__` for addressing.

So let's struct the project this way:

```
├─ root/
│  ├─ config/
│  │  ├─ config.php
│  ├─ helpers/
│  │  ├─ customFile.php
│  ├─ dir1/
│  │  ├─ function1.php
│  ├─ tempDir/
│  ├─ function2.php
│  ├─ useCustomFileFunction.php
```

And we can have this code in `config.php` file:

```
<?php

define("TEMP_DIR" , dirname(__DIR__) . "/tempDir/");
```

And we include the config.php in `function1.php` this way:

```
require(__DIR__ . "/../config/config.php");
```

And this way in `function2.php`:

```
require("config/config.php");
```

Now you can use the `TEMP_DIR` Constant to address the `tempDir` folder.